# Custom-shaped Aero glass window with WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi, aero

Is it possible to design a window in WPF that would allow an inner image to go over the borders of the aeroglass window?

An example of this is the Start Menu in Windows 7:

[image: overglass]

On this image the user icon is not within the borders of the aeroglass start menu window, but overlaps it.

How did MS achieve this?

My guess: those are two separate windows, stacked on top of one another?

Comment: more likely a single window with non-rectangular region as its boundary

Comment: Well, I can get a glass window with rectangular borders, but I can't get an image to stick out of the window are. And this is what they have here. A control sticking out of the window borders.

Comment: Note that the Windows 7 shell UI is, to the best of my knowledge, *not* implemented in WPF. :P

Comment: Probably not. But that doesn't change the fact, that these are most likely two separate windows. Both have a glass chrome by the way. I don't see other way then just use two windows for that. Whether it is WPF or C++/GDI or something. DirectX on the other hand may have different rules of layout.

Comment: Why do you believe it is two windows? Is that just a hunch?

Comment: @David, yes. I am just assuming they are.

Comment: Good question! I think, there are some tools that is able to prove or disprove an assumption about 2 windows. Probably it is owned window. Note also that this image have animated transparency when you move your mouse between start menu elements. And we can clearly see that it is usual Glass window besides. It is clearly not a custom shaped window.